# How to make the div at the screen center not lower right corner?

Tags: html, css

The following is want i wanted.

[image]

Here is my css code:

```
<html>
<header>
<style type="text/css">
*{margin:0 0 0 0;padding:0 0 0 0} 
div.block{width:400px;height:121px;border:1px solid red;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;}
div.box{float:left;}
div img{margin:0px;padding:0;width:121px;height:121px;float:left;}
div.description{float:left;border 1px solid red;margin:10px  50px;}
</style>

</header>
<body>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="box"><img src="test.jpg" /></div>  
        <div class="description">
                <p>music mane:  xxxxxxxx</p>
                <p>author:  yyyyyyyy</p>
                <p>publication：20081001</p>
                <p>language：english</p>
          </div>  
     </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the test.img.

[image]

The div is at the lower right corner of screen,how to make it at the screen center ?`top:50%;left:50%;` can't get the result.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

replace " div.block " with this code

```
div.block {
    width: 400px;
    height: 121px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this css

```
div.block{
width:400px;
height:121px;
border:1px solid red;
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin-top:-60.5px;
margin-left:-200px;
}
```

So the trick is to take left margin half of the width and top margin half of the height both in negative.

Answer (score 1):

You should use margin:auto to center

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
*{margin:0 0 0 0;padding:0 0 0 0} 
div.block{width:400px;height:121px;border:1px solid red;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;margin-top:-60px;margin-left:-200px;}
div.box{float:left;}
div img{margin:0px;padding:0;width:121px;height:121px;float:left;}
div.description{float:left;border 1px solid red;margin:10px  50px;}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/90ecazyn/)

**Or**

```
*{margin:0 0 0 0;padding:0 0 0 0} 
div.block{width:400px;height:121px;border:1px solid red;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;margin-left:-110px;}
div.box{float:left;}
div img{margin:0px;padding:0;width:121px;height:121px;float:left;}
div.description{float:left;border 1px solid red;margin:10px  50px;}
```

[**HERE MY DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/90ecazyn/1/)